# Is it possible to change between SELECT column based on an "IF" statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of 'mapped_products':

> product_id | price

A table of 'product_id_to_name':

> product_id | product_name

(please don't ask me why, this is an already built web-app i am working on).

A table of 'non_mapped_products':

> product_id | product_name

and a table of 'orders_history':

> prodeuct_id | order_date

My task **was** to get a list of 'product_names' that were previously ordered (by checking in the 'orders_hisoty' table). 
This is the query for this situation:

```
SELECT `non_mapped_products`.`product_name` 
FROM `non_mapped_products`
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1  FROM `orders_history` WHERE `orders_history`.`product_id` = `non_mapped_products`.`product_id`)
```

Now I noticed that I have the same products in my 'non_mapped_pruducts' within my 'mapped_products' table - same 'product_id', different 'product_name': 
I want to use the "product_name" if exist on my 'mapped_products' table instead of the one in tne 'non_mapped_products' table - if they do not exist I want to use the current 'product_name' from within the 'non_mapped_products'

I'm not so sure how to write this kind of query, it seems like an if/case statement under the select with an inner join (?)

```
SELECT (IF 'mapped_products'.'product_id' USE 'product_id_to_name'.'product_name' ELSE `non_mapped_products`.`product_name` ) 
FROM `non_mapped_products`
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1  FROM `orders_history` WHERE `orders_history`.`product_id` = `non_mapped_products`.`product_id`)
```

I'll be editing my post and add a few of false examples which do not work that i tried.

*Using MySQL database.*

```
SELECT

    CASE
        WHEN mapped_products.product_id = non_mapped_products.product_id
        THEN product_id_to_name.product_name
    ELSE
        non_mapped_products.product_name
    END
        AS product_name

FROM non_mapped_products

INNER JOIN mapped_products
    ON mapped_products.product_id = non_mapped_products.product_id
INNER JOIN product_id_to_name
    ON product_id_to_name.product_id = mapped_products.product_id

WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1  FROM orders_history WHERE orders_history.product_id = non_mapped_products.product_id)
```

returns : 
duplicate product names only from the `mapped_products` table

Answer (score 1):

If you `LEFT JOIN` your two product name tables to the order history table (or any other table which provides product_id), you will have access to both possible names. You can then use the `COALESCE()` function to obtain the first non-null value from the two name columns. You might want to create a VIEW of this to make life more convenient in other queries.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what this means :o

Comment: Can hyou please review my main post (I added an edit in the bottom)

Comment: Try this: SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE(product_id_to_name.product_name, non_mapped_products.product_name) as product_name FROM orders_history LEFT JOIN mapped_products USING (product_id) LEFT JOIN non_mapped_products USING (product_id);

Comment: I ge t this weird errror `#1054 - Unknown column 'product_id_to_name.product_name' in 'field list'` which does exist for 100%.

Comment: Sorry, replace the "LEFT JOIN mapped_products" part with "LEFT JOIN product_id_to_name".

Answer (score 0):

This should work. It's a bit long winded, but simple enough to read through:

TL;DR:

```
SELECT orders_history.product_id, product_id_to_name.product_name
FROM orders_history 
JOIN product_id_to_name ON orders_history.product_id = product_id_to_name.product_id 
UNION SELECT orders_history.product_id, non_mapped_products.product_name
FROM orders_history JOIN non_mapped_products ON orders_history.product_id = non_mapped_products.product_id
WHERE non_mapped_products.product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_id_to_name WHERE 1)
```

Going through the statement:

```
SELECT orders_history.product_id, product_id_to_name.product_name
FROM orders_history 
JOIN product_id_to_name ON orders_history.product_id = product_id_to_name.product_id
```

This will return all the `product_id_to_name.product_name` values (your preferred default name as per the OP) where there an associated order.

The second part:

```
UNION SELECT orders_history.product_id, non_mapped_products.product_name
FROM orders_history JOIN non_mapped_products ON orders_history.product_id = non_mapped_products.product_id
WHERE non_mapped_products.product_id 
NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_id_to_name WHERE 1)
```

This combines the result of the previous statement with selecting the `non_mapped_products.product_name` where the `non_mapped_product.product_id` isn't present in `product_id_to_name.product_id`.

The net result is all the `order_history.product_id` fields along with the `product_name` chosen preferably from `product_id_to_name` but with a fallback to the value from `non_mapped_products`.

Comment: (I edited my main post) - Do you think it's possible to do the same not using the `orders_history` as the main table? (It's supper huge and indexed in a horrible way)

Comment: How can I `SELECT orders_history.product_id, product_id_to_name.product_name` if not all `product_id`s are listed under `product_id_to_name.product_name`?

Comment: You are forming a union of that along with the later `select` statement. The join will ensure that only those common to both are returned

Comment: Is it possible to alter the database layout? It seems like you've inherited a mess so if possible it might be better to reconfigure things.